# Ubuntu phone - cannot pin app to launcher

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

I am attempting to pin an app to the Ubuntu phone (E5 Aquaris) launcher, but when holding the temporary icon the menu to pin the icon does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **system settings** scroll down to **Reset phone** select **Reset Launcher**, confirm the same and it should work :-)

Answer (score -2):

Are you trying to pin to bar on left? If so open the app you want, then when the app is open slide from left to get bar up, then hold the app icon (on left bar) there for a few seconds, the option to pin should arrive.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: It seems that Thomas knows how it should work. There is no new information for him in your answer. In his question Thomas states, that the menu to pin the app to the launch does not appear when holding the app icon.